# Good way to create observer design pattern in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I am trying to implement observer design pattern in C++ as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class observer
{
    public:
        observer() = default;
        ~observer() = default;

        virtual void notify() = 0;
};

class subject
{
    vector <observer *> vec;

    public:
        subject() = default;
        ~subject() = default;

        void _register(observer *obj)
        {
            vec.push_back(obj);
        }

        void unregister(observer *obj)
        {
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
            {
                if(vec[i] == obj)
                {
                    cout << "found elem. unregistering" << endl;
                    vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(i == vec.size())
            {
                cout << "elem not found to unregister" << endl;
            }
        }

        void notify()
        {
            vector <observer *>::iterator it = vec.begin();
            while(it != vec.end())
            {
                (*it)->notify();
                it ++;
            }
        }
};

class obsone : public observer
{
    void notify()
    {
        cout << "in obsone notify" << endl;
    }
};

class obstwo : public observer
{
    void notify()
    {
        cout << "in obstwo notify" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    subject sub;

    obsone *one = new obsone();
    obstwo *two = new obstwo();

    sub._register(one);   
    sub._register(two);
    sub.notify();

    sub.unregister(one);
    sub.notify();

    //delete two;
    //sub.notify();

    return 0;
}
```

I am registering the objects with the subject explicitly. Is it the correct way of doing it or do I need to register through observer class only. Are there any problems with the above approach?

Comment: Instead of an abstract observer class, just use a `std::function` as callback, pass in lambdas.

Comment: I would choose another naming convention than prefix underscore, because that's used for so much else and is reserved in the global namespace.

Comment: i like a signal/slot mechanism similar to boost::signals2, here is a minimal implementation: https://github.com/skeller1982/SimpleSignals

Comment: GoF patterns are often not applicable to C++ code. In particular, there is no need to create this complex hierarchy of classes (forgetting to make your destructor virtual along the way) when you have `std::function` and lambdas.

Comment: Note that `register` is a keyword and can't be used as a name of a function.

Comment: When you have a good answer. Submit for code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MartinYork: I think (but not sure) that pedantically by the standard, instead of just `enum Id: uint64_t {};` one would have to do something like `enum Id: uint64_t { max = uint64_t(-1) };` so that perverse compiler wouldn't generate a trap or something when an "out of bounds" enumeration value is used. But when at all possible I just plainly refuse to obfuscate the code to satisfy someone's impractical not-at-all-what-one-would-expect formalism. And SO isn't a place where one could get a reasonable discussion and resolution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Not sure what the comment is about?

Comment: @MartinYork: Code review. I addressed the IMO second most significant problem with a Stack Exchange code review, that of not knowing the rationale of the decisions in the code. The most significant problem being that the reviewers can sound authoritative without even understanding the basics of programming, as I experienced when asked for review of some JavaScript code, where a number of the reviewers didn't appear to understand hex, but still had strong and authoritative-sounding opinions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example of doing the callbacks with lambdas and `function` objects in the callback collection.

The details can vary greatly! So, this code is not “the” way, but just your code rewritten in one specific way, out of a myriad possibilities. But it hopefully shows the general idea in modern C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>               // std::function
#include <stdint.h>                 // uint64_t
#include <unordered_map>            // std::unordered_map
#include <utility>                  // std::move    
#include <vector>                   // std::vector
using namespace std;

namespace my
{
    using Callback = function<void()>;
    template< class Key, class Value > using Map_ = unordered_map<Key, Value>;

    class Subject
    {
    public:
        enum Id: uint64_t {};

    private:
        Map_<uint64_t, Callback> m_callbacks;

        static auto id_value()
            -> uint64_t&
        {
            static uint64_t the_id;
            return the_id;
        }

    public:
        auto add_listener( Callback cb )
            -> Id
        {
            const auto id = Id( ++id_value() );
            m_callbacks.emplace( id, move( cb ) );
            return id;
        }

        auto remove_listener( const Id id )
            -> bool
        {
            const auto it = m_callbacks.find( id );
            if( it == m_callbacks.end() )
            {
                return false;
            }
            m_callbacks.erase( it );
            return true;
        }

        void notify_all() const
        {
            for( const auto& pair : m_callbacks )
            {
                pair.second();
            }
        }
    };
}

struct Observer_1
{
    void notify() { cout << "Observer_1::notify() called." << endl; }
};

struct Observer_2
{
    void notify() { cout << "Observer_2::notify() called." << endl; }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    my::Subject     subject;
    Observer_1      one;
    Observer_2      two;

    using Id = my::Subject::Id;
    const Id listener_id_1 = subject.add_listener( [&]{ one.notify(); } );
    const Id listener_id_2 = subject.add_listener( [&]{ two.notify(); } );

    cout << "After adding two listeners:" << endl;
    subject.notify_all();
    cout << endl;

    subject.remove_listener( listener_id_1 )
        and (cout << "Removed listener 1." << endl)
        or (cout << "Did not find registration of listener 1." << endl);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "After removing or attempting to remove listener 1:" << endl;
    subject.notify_all();
}
```