# How to declare std::function for any member function with specific signature?

Tags: c++

I'm making a coarse&simplified mimic of Qt's signal connect, and want to implement an API like:

```
class MyEvent;
class MyObject;
static void connect( MyObject* sender, 
                     std::string eventName,
                     MyObject* listener,
                     SomeCallable listenerMethod );
```

And here are traits for `SomeCallable`:

- it would be instance methods of `MyObject` or its subclasses;
- it could have any name;
- it has one argument of `const MyEvent&` and returns nothing.

How could I write `std::function` for it? Or is it ever possible by only using `std::function`?

As a last resort, I still can use `std::function<void(const MyEvent&)>` as `SomeCallable`, and let API users to make a bind:

```
struct HisListener: public MyObject
{
   void foo( const MyEvent& );
};
connect( some_sender, "some_event", some_listener, std::bind(&HisListener::foo, some_listener, std::place_holders::_1) );
```

But such approach does not express any relations between `listener` and `listenerMethod`, and I'm attempting to make it more restricted.

Comment: Suggestions: 1. avoid C-style pointers 2. mention the name of the design pattern being implemented (observer) 3. mention why/what-for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good way to create observer design pattern in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848507/good-way-to-create-observer-design-pattern-in-c)

Comment: @ÖöTiib I know the pattern you mentioned but I don't want to use it, as I want the callback methods to have arbitrary name.

Comment: @Vorac I use raw pointers here as they won't hold ownership for each other. The connection will be automatically destroyed on either sender or listener is destroyed.

Comment: @jiandingzhe programming is still closer to religion than science, thus: never ever use C pointers. All code is written for the humans after You, instead of for the CPU. [And to finally say something useful](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).

Comment: @Vorac I belong to the C++ heresy that raw pointers are good for representing non-owned, copyable references, as I'm not using the newest C++20 and there's no `raw_pointer`. The correctness of the behavior is ENSURED in destructor of MyObject.

Comment: <upvote> to Your question. I firmly disagree with You but do respect You for stating irrefutable truths.

Comment: @Vorac `std::weak_ptr` requires that the pointee be owned by a `std::shared_ptr`. What do you do about instances in automatic storage?

Comment: @jiandingzhe If you look at the code in answer to question (not in the question) then  the add_listener accepts arbitrary nameless lambdas there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write a template to do the binding for the user

```
static void connect( MyObject* sender, 
                     std::string eventName,
                     MyObject* listener,
                     std::function<void(const MyEvent&)> listenerMethod );

template <std::derived_from<MyObject> Receiver>
static void connect( MyObject* sender, 
                     std::string eventName,
                     Receiver* listener,
                     void (Receiver::*listenerMethod)(const MyEvent&) )
{
    connect(sender, eventName, listener, std::bind_front(listenerMethod, listener));
}
```